# Relationship Between 2 Algebraic Expressions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, algebra

Does anyone know of a library or algorithm (preferably in JavaScript) that can compare two algebraic predicates and tell me whether...

one would solve the other, eg.

`a := ((x + 10) < 100) && y == 20`

`b := y < 30`

or they're mutually exclusive to each other, eg.

`a := x > 10`

`b := y < 30`

or contradict each other, eg.

`a := x > 10`

`b := x < 10`

Many thanks

*disclaimer*: my algebra is rusty so apologies if the terminology is incorrect!

Comment: Are a, b supposed to be numbers (as in "a := x + 10") or boolean true/false (as in "a := x > 10")?

Comment: good spot, will correct. In this case they should all evaluate to booleans, but there might be nested arithmetic inside..

Comment: I think "orthogonal" or "independent" is a better description here than "mutually exclusive". The latter is more similar to your later "contradict".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, noted! But independence wouldn't imply contradiction though, I still want to differentiate between those two cases

Comment: @ComethTheNerd Right. Might point is that it might be (slightly) clearer if your cases were called "contained", "independent", and "contradict".

Comment: In my notes here I've been using set theory terminology for those scenarios, but if your terms are the proper algebraic ones I'm happy to change!